# How to split and store XML in SQL Server 2008 R2 using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<searchResult>

    <pagination>
        <itemsPerPage>{Number of Inventories per Page}</itemsPerPage>
        <numberOfItems>{Number of Inventories}</numberOfItems>
    </pagination>

    <itemList>
        <item>
            {Requested Salesforce fields e.g:}
            <Id>{Salesforce Id}</Id>
            <Name>{Name}</Name>
            <pb__IsForSale__c>{e.g.}false</pb__IsForSale__c>
            <pb__IsForLease__c>{e.g.}true</pb__IsForLease__c>
            <pb__ItemDescription__c>{Item Description}</pb__ItemDescription__c>
            <pb__PurchaseListPrice__c>{Item List Price e.g.:}2000000.00</pb__PurchaseListPrice__c>
            <CurrencyIsoCode>{Currency Iso Code e.g:}EUR</CurrencyIsoCode>
            <pb__UnitBedrooms__c>{Number of Bedrooms}</pb__UnitBedrooms__c>

            <asset>
                <Id>{internal Propertybase InventoryAsset Id}</Id>
                <category>{Images, Videos or Documents}</category>
                <isExternalLink>false</isExternalLink>
                <title>{title}</title>
                <filename>{original name of the uploaded file}</filename>
                <url>{full url to image/video/document}</url>
                <thumbnailUrl>{full url to thumbnail image}</thumbnailUrl>
                <midresUrl>{full url to thumbnail image}</midresUrl>
                <tags>{comma separated tags}</tags>
                <mimeType>{e.g. image/jpeg}</mimeType>
            </asset>

            <asset>
                <Id>{internal Propertybase InventoryAsset Id}</Id>
                <category>{Images, Videos or Documents}</category>
                <isExternalLink>true</isExternalLink>
                <title>{title}</title>
                <url>{full url to image/video/document}</url>
                <tags>{comma separated tags}</tags>
            </asset>

            <asset>
               {...}
            </asset>
            {more assets ...}

        </item>

        <item>
            {...}
        </item>
        {more items ...}

    </itemList>

</searchResult>
```

Well I have the above XML from which I need to store the item tag in a database table along with its child nodes as attributes, and have to store the asset tag and its child nodes in another table with the item id as foreign key from the item table, How do I do it done a lots of googeling but can't get of a way to get it to work

Comment: `while (reader.Read())
{
if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
{
reader.Read();
Response.Write(reader.Value + "</br>");
}    
}`

I could get up-to this point only. Not a single idea how to proceed further

Comment: Did you try using `XDocument` instead of `XmlReader`?

Comment: yeah I tried but couldn't understand that as well

Comment: And what exactly did you not understand? Your question is very general.

Comment: How come it is general?
I asked for complete code segment to perform the said operation on the above given XML format

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works - we don't "give teh codez". We will help with specific issues, so long as you show us your efforts and articulate what exactly you are having problems with. Your question is just a request for us to do your work for you.

Comment: ok I got your point now, sorry I got you wrong, the point at which I am stuck is that I don't know how to split the document nodes and any help in proper direction would be appreciated, I mean any book or link would also be appreciated, it made me just so frustrated that after two days of struggle I could only display all the data of the XML on screen sjust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to select all `Item` nodes.

Using XPath (with `SelectNodes`, for example) this would be `\\Item` - this will produce a node set that you can iterate over.

Comment: I tried this `string fileName = "D://project_elysian//data.xml";
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);
        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

XPathExpression expr;
expr = nav.Compile(expression);
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);
try
{
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
XmlNode nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
Response.Write("price: " + nav2.Value + "<br/>");
}` but it only gives me all the nodes at that specific depth and name, for example if I select `\item\asset\url` this code gives me all the  elements at this depth within all the items

Comment: @mamoorkhan - Much better to edit your question and post the code in it then in a comment.

Comment: @mamoorkhan - I gave you the expression to use.